# npm install error: "The build tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found"

Tags: msbuild, npm, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, node-gyp

While running an `npm install` that required a node-gyp rebuild, the following build error was thrown:

> MSB8020: The build tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot
>   be found. To build using the v120 build tools, please install v120
>   build tools. Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual
>   Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the
>   solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution"

#### System Information

- Windows 10 (x64)
- Visual Studio 2015
- node v0.12.7
- npm v2.11.3
- node-gyp v2.0.1

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use the msvs_version param: `npm install --msvs_version=2015`

## What if the msvs_version param doesn't work?

If the msvs_version param doesn't work, it's probably because you don't have a Visual C++ 2015 build environment installed.

### Install Visual C++ Build Environment

#### Option 1: Visual Studio 2015

1. During VS2015 installation, select "Custom". Or, if you've already installed VS2015, go to Windows' "Uninstall or change a program" > select VS2015 from the list > click "Change" > click "Modify"
2. Check the "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" option, under "Programming Languages" > "Visual C++"
3. Finish the VS2015 installation

#### Option 2: Visual C++ Build Tools 2015

As an alternative to VS2015, you can install the [Visual C++ Build Tools 2015](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126) released by Microsoft:

1. During VC++ installation, select "Custom"
2. Check the "Windows 8.1 SDK" and "Windows 10 SDK" options
3. Finish the VC++ installation

### Use msvs_version

Now that a Visual C++ 2015 build environment has been installed, you can tell npm to use it via the msvs_version param:

1. Open PowerShell
2. Use the msvs_version param: `npm install --msvs_version=2015`

#### Config Options (not required)

Optionally, instead of specifying the msvs_version at the command prompt, you can configure npm to always include the msvs_version param by adding it to your npmrc or package.json:

**npmrc**

Open PowerShell and run `npm config set msvs_version 2015`, which will add this param to your user npmrc file. Henceforth, every time you run `npm install`, as this user, the `msvs_version=2015` param will automatically be included

> optionally, you can include the global flag `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global` if you plan on logging in with different Windows accounts, and you want this setting to apply to all accounts on the machine

**package.json**

Modify your project's package.json file to include:

```
"config": {
  "msvs_version": 2015
}
```

Henceforth, every time you run `npm install`, for this project, the `msvs_version=2015` param will automatically be included

---

*Article Revisions*

1. *Steps revised after further investigation inspired by Chuck's comment about the v120 toolset (thanks @ChuckWalbourn)*
2. *Added config options*
3. *Added VC++ Build Tools option*
4. *Updated VC++ Build Tools link for official release*

Comment: You can also install the ``v120`` toolset by selecting "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools" in the [custom setup options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers.aspx) for VS 2015.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn what appears to be happening when you select the "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools" option is, it's selecting the "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" option as a dependency, and that is what's actually installing the required toolset

Comment: I faced a situation while installing bcrypt, 
    "npm i bcrypt --msvs_version=2013" 
worked for me

Comment: I could *swear* I selected all the options when installing VS2015, yet, upon reading this answer and checking, I found the C++ unchecked. Agrh!

Comment: Great answer. 

I was able to install C++ tools using new project -> C++ -> install C++ tools. Otherwise all the other tips listed here helped, primarily msvs_version=2015

Comment: But what does one do when the build tools *are actually installed*?

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add a comment to 2Toad's answer but stackoverflow doesn't let me.
You can set the msvs_version globally with this command:

```
npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
```

This saves you putting it in each projects config object.

Comment: why the downvote? setting the config globally via the command line isn't mentioned in the other answer

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading: using the `npm config set msvs_version 2015` setting without the `--global` flag achieves the goal of not having to put it in each project's config. The `--global` flag is only needed if you plan on logging in with different Windows accounts, and you want that setting to apply to all accounts on that machine

Answer (score 2):

I'll share this answer since none of the other fixes resolved my issue. I was having the same errors but setting the msvs param:

`npm install --msvs_version=2015`

was not solving the problem. I could see that it was looking in the wrong place for the toolset no matter what I did.

Long story short I learned that MSBuild is now packaged with Visual Studio and no longer packaged with .NET. Sure enough I had this entry in the PATH variable:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;
```

and consequently the wrong (old) version of MSBuild was being called. I removed this entry and added the following path which is relevant for VS2015:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks. Took me a while to figure that out

Comment: this is the only correct answer, setting variables is not enough.
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin;%PATH%
or
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;%PATH%

Answer (score 1):

I already spend 2 days installing all VS versions...

```
npm install oracledb --msvs_version=2015
```

Return all lot of errors :

```
[..]node-gyp\6.9.1\include\node\v8.h(18): fatal error C1083[..]
```

Using

```
npm install oracledb --msvs_version=2013
```

Return a lot of warnings, compile but doesn't work properly after.

```
[..]warning C4995: 'v8::Value::ToUint32'[..]
```

This is my worst ever experience with a npm module. What a waste of time :/

Comment: I re-install VS2015, clean the system path variable with all variable in installation readme. Got all the warning but it's working properly now ...
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: More than a year have passed and I'm having the same problem... I'm very disappointed with this package too, if I could choose I won't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting version to 2015 didn't help for me. Try setting it to 2013 instead:

npm config set msvs_version **2013**

or

npm config set msvs_version 2015