# NPM modules compiling issues in Windows (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, visual-c++, npm

I want to install `mean-cli` **NPM** module in order to work with [mean.io](http://mean.io/) stack. The problem I have is with compiling some `C` files while installing `mean-cli`.

I entered `npm install -g --msvs_version=2013 mean-cli` as Administrator in windows powershell. Also I have installed `VS 2015 community edition` and I have set `GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013` in my user environment variables.

**System :**

```
Windows 7.1 64bit
```

**Error :**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build t
ools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, please install v120 bui
ld tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-cli
ck the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". 


[C:\Users\Ramin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\node
_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:2
70:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node
-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ramin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_mo
dules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN installMany nopt was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany npmlog was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany request was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany semver was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar-pack was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany mkdirp was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany rc was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany rimraf was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This seems like it might be more of an [tag:msbuild] problem than a c++ one, especially since the output appears to be grumbling about not finding the right version of the Microsoft build tools, more than throwing any specific C or C++ related errors.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, OK what do you suggest?

Comment: I was suggesting possibly better tags for your question. perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556295/npm-install-error-the-build-tools-for-v120-platform-toolset-v120-cannot) is what you're looking for? Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886391/vs-2012-project-failed-to-build-because-of-missing-toolset)?